I have 35,000 km on my Marathon Mondials since 2019, is it time to change to them?
I have been using these on my Kona Sutra bike for the past 5 years on rail trails, gravel, road and regular commute.
I do see signs of wear like tyre surface, like you can see a little bit of tyre peeling.
But still these are working fine and in the past 5 years I haven't had a single puncture.
Should I go ahead and change it just in case?

The mileage itself is not too important. How they look like and how they ride is. But you cannot really assess that from the text description.

What do you mean by "peeling"? If the rubber has degraded(cracking, crumbling, peeling(??)) or the threads are showing I'd replace it. Otherwise it's a judgement call and matter of preference.

You might want to add some pictures of the most worn bits.  Marathon Mondials should be among the longest-lasting tyres out there, though there will come a point when their off-road grip has suffered.  Even so, the back wouldn't last me that long (as a heavy rider)

Maintenance strategies are on a spectrum.
On the one end of the spectrum:
"I'll fix it when it's broken. I'm going to get every last mile out of it"
This philosophy makes sense if you have a good plan for when things go sideways. You are never too far from home or you can phone a friend for example.
On the other end of the spectrum:
"I'll replace it long before it's completely broken because I don't want it to break down on me out on the road" philosophy.
This philosophy does not completely prevent things from breaking but it does reduce the chances (which is why, at this end of the spectrum, people will carry spares). This makes sense for people who will be far from any kind of support.
Since it is a spectrum there are many variations in between these two positions. For example, you may decide to wait on fixing things but carry spares. You may decide that some things can wait and other things cannot.
You need to evaluate your situation and decide on a plan that gives you a sense of safety/comfort on the road.

You should replace a tyre urgently if:

Carcass (the fabric underneath the rubber tread) is significantly damaged, for example a >5mm cut which allows the tube to poke through and the tyre to bulge. This also applies to the sidewall.
Rubber tread worn to the point that the carcass or puncture protection (usually rubber in a bright color) is coming through.

You should replace soon if:

Significant dry rot, i.e. cracks in the rubber. A small amount is pretty normal, but in really bad cases the cracks go all the way to the carcass and can also lead to carcass damage. Dry rot also means the rubber is harder, so you have less grip.
Rubber tread worn to the point that the Tread Wear Indicator (TWI) dimples – if your tyre has them – are no longer visible. If your tyre does not have them you have to estimate remaining tread by looking at the tread pattern. If you get more punctures or have less grip on soft ground because your tread is worn down you have to make a judgement call on when to replace.


Note (@Bikeoddity) that the puncture protection layer, being much harder rubber, is another thing that's not very good for grip
